# Стоит ли хранить модификатор доступа пользователя в его сессии?

Tags: java, servlet

Я хочу сохранить ключ доступа admin/user в `HttpSession` но не знаю правильно ли это? Пользователь может отредактировать свою сессию и получить доступ к роли администратора?

```
final HttpSession session = req.getSession();
session.setAttribute("access", access);
```

Comment: Если хотите поэксперементировать, то можете хранить там ключ доступа (можно и ид пользователя впридачу), но лучше не надо. Пользователь видит сессию например так: `Cookie:JSESSIONID=A6F9A23571CBB66B795AD6F3163B9EDB` , поэтому поменять на клиентской стороне можно только этот идентификатор (но не значения в сессии, которое меняется только на серверной стороне).

Comment: Нет, не стоит. По той простой причине, что нельзя просто брать и доверять информации, которая приходит от пользователя. А если вы будете каждый раз проверять в коде, действительно ли у данного пользователя есть такие права, то и смысла держать эту информацию в сессии и не будет. **Но это если этот ключ уходит клиенту** (не знаю как именно работает `HttpSession`). Если ключ хранится только на сервере и подгружается по ID сессии, то должно быть нормально.

Comment: а что представляет из себя ключ доступа?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman у каждого пользователя в базе есть поле `success` которое принимает значение `user` или `admin` которое используется в фильтрах чтобы определить кому какой функционал показывать на клиенте, и это значение я хочу записывать в сессию чтобы не лазать каждый раз в базу, тоесть использовать объект сессии как кэш.

Comment: @Regen я вот тоже не знаю как работает `HttpSession` и какая ее часть храниться в браузере а какая существует только в вида java объекта и tomcat. Почитать бы где нибудь поглубже про этот процесс...

Comment: @MrFylypenco а почему вы считаете что лучше не надо какие могут быть проблемы? Или может просто в сервлет-контексте потокобезопасную мапу завести и в ней все хранить?

Comment: Если найдёте почитать что-то толковое, то там обязательно будет про стандартный механизм авторизации с помощью ролей. Как ограничивать доступ по ролям к страницам, на вызов методов, как программным способом проверить есть ли у пользователя данная роль.

Comment: @Sergey сложно отличить толковое от не толкового когда толковое еще не прочитано... если подбросите хорошую статью буду очень признателен.

Comment: Почитайте руководство JavaEE. По крайней мере узнаете ключевые слова чтобы гуглить. Почитайте руководство spring. Там своя секретность, похожая на вашу, через фильтры.

Comment: @Sergey руководство Java EE очень большое мне нужны ключевые слова что бы в нем для сначала найти...

Comment: @Pavel да оно не большое. и оставляет больше вопросов, чем раскрывает. но есть ключевые слова, термины, название каких-то явлений, по которым уже можно икать инфу более что ли целенаправленно. Можно даже спецификации JSR почитать. servlet-3_0-final-spec например про сервлеты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете смело сохранять эту информацию в **HttpSession**. Только помните, что сессия привязана к серверу и если у вас их больше одного, то надо сессию синхронизировать.

Если уровень доступа для клиента будет изменён, то сессию надо будет сбросить, так как в ней будет старый уровень.